# Magento 2 Install XHProf in nginx?

Tags: magento2, nginx

I am trying to setup XHProf in nginx server but some of reason I am unable to success.
I follow and read [XHProof magento 2](https://www.goivvy.com/blog/magento-2-ttfb-optimization) Any one try and success to configure it.